# String length using pattern matching technique

Tags: string, data-structures, pattern-matching

What is the maximum number of comparisons required to search a string of length L in a text whose length is T using first pattern matching technique?

Comment: What is "first pattern matching technique"?

Answer (score 0):

[Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) gives you the time complexity of `O(L+T)`.